Error 404 redirect not working in Django and static files not showing in edge
I am developing a single page webapp where I am trying to configure the error page if page not found so I have added proper settings but still my redirect not working on error page.
Here is my settings.py
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-0t^!2rh2#u8fx1k(@+#oik8l$5i^xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']  # Add your domain here

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'ArchanaComputersHome',
    'django_dump_die',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django_dump_die.middleware.DumpAndDieMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ArchanaComputers.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ArchanaComputers.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


And following is my urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from ArchanaComputersHome import views
from django.conf.urls import handler404
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


handler404 = views.page_not_found

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('admission-request', views.admission_request, name='admission_request'),
    
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


admin.site.site_header = "Archana Computers"
admin.site.site_title = "Archana Computers Admin Portal"
admin.site.index_title = "Welcome to Archana Computers Admin Portal"

And here is my page_not_found function
def page_not_found(request, exception=None):
    """
    This function handles the 404 page not found error.

    Parameters:
    - request: The HTTP request object.

    Returns:
    - A rendered HTML template for the 404 page not found error.

    Raises:
    - None
    """
    title = 'Page Not Found'
    context = {
        'title': title
    }
    return render(request, 'error/404.html', context)

and here is my 404.html template:
{% extends "error/base/error-base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% comment %}
    This template extends the base template and includes various sections of the home page.
    It also loads static files for better site accessibility.
{% endcomment %}


{% block content %}
<section>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center vh-100">
        <div class="text-center row">
            <div class=" col-md-6">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/09/12/31/error-2129569__340.jpg" alt=""
                    class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class=" col-md-6 mt-5">
                <p class="fs-3"> <span class="text-danger">Opps!</span> Page not found.</p>
                <p class="lead">
                    The page you’re looking for doesn’t exist.
                </p>
                <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-primary">Go Home</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}

also executed python manage.py collectstatic command but still issue persist
Please check and let me know what is the issue if possible.

handler404 = "views.page_not_found" << make this into a string.

Hi @Nesi I have tried that already and it gives me following error => ERRORS:
?: (urls.E008) The custom handler404 view 'views.page_not_found' could not be imported.
HINT: No module named 'views'
